# How to change a media's aspect ratio in WMP ActiveX?

Tags: activex, windows-media-player, wmp, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm building an application that has a WMP ActiveX and I'm working with 720x576 PAL medias. I increased the WMP ActiveX width because of I want to play these medias like they are 16:9 but WMP ActiveX did not strech the media.

When I tried to change `Player.strechToFit` property, it did not change anything. The ActiveX always maintains the aspect ratio.
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

How do I play these medias like they are 16:9? Can I force WMP ActiveX to do this?